# How to modify this .bat file to include the name of the parent folder?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, automation

I've created this .bat file and added it to my context menu to help me quickly create a set of folders with predefined names when I'm starting a new project, this saves me time from creating all these folders manually

```
@ECHO OFF
md 01_Project-Brief 02_Project-Assets 03_Project-Research 04_Project-Snapshots 05_Project-Process 06_Project-Mockups
```

my process goes like this, whenever I want to start a new project, first I create a new folder and give it the project name, for example, "East Oasis" then open that folder and inside it I run the batch file from context menu it creates the project folders,

I want the names of the project folders created to have the name of the project (the parent folder) included in them instead of having just static names

Example:

[image: project folders]

Any help is appreciated. and thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REM get the name of the current folder
       for %%a in (.) do set "curpath=%%~nxa"

REM now make the directories (just one to show the idea)        
       md "06_%curpath%-Mockups"
```

[...]

Comment: This worked like a charm, Thanks a lot Paul

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

cd /d "%~dp0" && set "_cd=%cd%"
set "_cd=%_cd:\=" & set /A i+=1 & set "_cd!_i!=%"
set "_folder=Brief,Assets,Research,Snapshots,Process,Mockups"

for %%i in (%_folder%)do set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && =;(
     "%ComSPec%" /v:on /e /c "mkdir "0!_cnt!_!_cd!_%%~i" );=

timeout 05 | tree /a /f & endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, It's best to leave Batch behind, and use more modern methods where the code written actually makes sense, like Python, NodeJS, or PHP.

I mainly stick with PHP out of habit to automate things like these.

```php
<?php

// List directories in the current dir.
$dirs = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

// Find and replace variables.
$find = "_Project";
$replace = "_East Oasis";

// Loop through each directory and replace the name.
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
  // Skip dir if doesn't contain the $find term.
  if (!str_contains($dir, $find))
    continue;

  // Replace $find with $replace in the string $dir.
  $new_name = str_replace($find, $replace, $dir);

  // Rename the old name $dir to the $new_name.
  rename($dir, $new_name);
}

?>
```

Result:
[image: Result]